# How do I change the number of available workspaces in Cinnamon?

Tags: gui, cinnamon

I am used to four workspaces in Gnome, but now that I have Cinnamon installed I only have two. Can I increase the number? If so, how?

Comment: Submitted a bug report: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4510

Comment: See also https://github.com/hernejj/workspace-grid-cinnamon-applet/tree/master/workspace-grid@hernejj which adds the ability to arrange workspaces in a grid.

Answer (score 73):

What Cinnamon version do you use? As far as I know, their latest version can do this seamlessly.

In my Linux Mint 14 I can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> to show all workspaces, and then click <kbd>+</kbd> button on the right edge of the screen to add new workspace.

You may want to check [cinnamon 1.6 release page](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?p=207). Clem already explained how to do this over there.

Answer (score 17):

For those who don't want to dynamically add workspaces by clicking some "hot corner":

CLI:

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon number-workspaces
4
$ gsettings set org.cinnamon number-workspaces 12
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon number-workspaces
12
```

GUI:

Open `dconf-editor`, navigate to `org/cinnamon/number-workspaces`, set the new value.

Log out and log back in again for the changes to take effect.

(I think it helps to have a fixed number of workspaces, like 12, in which case Super + F1-F12 could be assigned to directly switch to one of those. But that's a matter of taste.)

---

**Update**:

The option has moved:

> (Deprecated) Number of Workspaces - pre-2.6, even though you shouldn't
>   use it even on <2.6 releases. Use org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences
>   num-workspaces instead.

So the command would now be:

```
$ gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 12
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces
```

Comment: This was very helpful for one who has unbinded ctrl-alt-up.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the context menu on the Workspace switcher applet:

[image: Workspace switcher]

Comment: Just an additional hint which helped me. If you don't have this Applet. It might not be on by default. (As in Debian default installation) You can add it with `System Configuration -> Applets`

Answer (score 5):

At least in Linux Mint 13 you can also move the mouse pointer to the upper left corner to see, add or remove workspaces. To remove one of them you just need to place the pointer on it and a "x" will appear on its upper right corner: if you click on it it will be taken away and the opened applications/windows will be moved to the one to the left (if missing then to the one to the right). To continue using any workspace just click on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to Mint 16 and Cinnamon 2, the same thing works:

1. Ctrl-Alt-Up brings up the desktops
2. The "+" on the right increments the number of available desktops.
3. If a finger stutter puts an extra desktop on, each desktop has an "x" in the upper right corner that will drop the number back down.

Answer (score 1):

In Mint 13 xfce: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (main menu) > Settings > Workspaces

There, you simply change the number.

Comment: Hmm, this is XFCE, not Cinnamon?  Somewhat mystifyingly, the Cinnamon Workspaces settings pane (as of Debian 8.1) does not allow you to change the number of workspaces.

Comment: only this one helped me. I have Linux mint Cinnamon Sylvia and this shortcut showed the workspaces

Answer (score 0):

Use Gnome Tweaks. In the Workspaces menu you can configure the number of workspaces.